# Batch script to only keep the last part of a filename and its extension

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder which contains multiple files with this format :
[image]

I would like to rename all of these files so that I get :
391047.png, 416945.pdf, 416946.pdf, ..., 437703.png

I wish to do this with a batch cmd

If someone could help me with this, I am really not familiar with batch commands !

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without full specifics of your question I can guess that you want to grab the last hyphen delimited portion of your file name and rename it to that.  If the output on the screen looks correct remove the `ECHO` that precedes the `REN` command.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
REM Capture output of DIR, don't grab batch file and call the rename subroutine
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /a-d /b *.* ^|findstr /V "%~nx0"') DO CALL :RENAME "%%~G"
pause
ENDLOCAL
REM This terminates the batch file
GOTO :EOF

REM Functions below.
:RENAME
REM assign passed argument to a variable
set "file=%~nx1"
REM Get last part of file name based on hyphen as delimiter
set "last=%file:-=" & set "last=%"
REM rename passed file to last part of file name
echo ren "%~1" "%last%"
REM ends the subroutine
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running in the same folder as your files, if not, edit:

```bat
cd/d "%~dp0" ==> cd/d "d:\your\folder"
```

For this task, if all of your file names end with exactly 6 digits / characters and you need to do this in any subfolder, try the **`for`** loop using **`where.exe`**:

```bat
@echo off 
cd/d "%~dp0"
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r . *^| %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /v "bat  cmd"
')do set "_file=%%~ni" && cmd/v/c echo/ ren "%%~fi" "!_file:~-6!%~xi"
```

- Or, in command line:

```bat
@cd/d "d:\your\folder" & @for /f tokens^=* %i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r . *^| %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /v "bat  cmd"')do @set "_file=%~ni" && cmd/v/c @echo/ ren "%~fi" "!_file:~-6!%~xi"
```

Read more about **[Where.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)** and **[some example here](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)**

Comment: One tweak you may want to make is to set the file variable to the file name only without the extension. Then sub-string for the last 6 characters and use the `%%~xi` with the rename. You never know if they might have word documents or whatever else with 4 byte file extensions.

Comment: @Squashman Is for learn a little more the because I'm here.. Yep. thank you....

Answer (score 1):

And just for something a little bit different from the other existing answers:

```bat
@Set "MyDir=C:\Users\Tibo\Desktop\MyDirectory"
@For /F "EOL=|Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B/A-D-S "%MyDir%\*-*" 2^>NUL')Do @(
    Set "BaseName=%%~nG"&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For %%H In ("!BaseName:-=\!")Do @EndLocal&Ren "%MyDir%\%%G" "%%~nxH%%~xG")
```

This one lists all none system files in `%MyDir%`, *(which you should modify to suit your actual location)*, whose name contains at least one hyphen, `-`. It then replaces all hyphens in the file basenames with a backslash, and renames the original using the part after the last `\`. It does that by implementing `~nx`, *(to allow for names like `2002-006-Moi-105472.5.jpg`)* and adds the extension, `~x` back on. The script uses delayed expansion because it is both creating, and using, a variable within the same code block.

Answer (score 1):

How about yet one more way? The biggest assumption this makes is that there is a HYPHEN-MINUS before the digits preceding the extension. When you are sure the the renaming will be done correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` command.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\src\t\last4' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object {" ^
            "if ($_.Name -match '.*-(\d*\..*)$') {" ^
                "Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $Matches[1] -WhatIf" ^
            "}" ^
        "}"
```

Naturally, this would be easier and cleaner if it is written as a PowerShell script.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\src\t\last4' |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Name -match '.*-(\d*\..*)$') {
            Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $Matches[1] -WhatIf
        }
    }
```